# Sanitization against SQL Injection for Input going into an Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, sql-injection, informix

Hello I have been working for a while with PHP and MySQL. Now I am working in a PHP-Informix and PHP-Oracle environment. I have always used mysql_real_escape_string for the data going into the database. I am presently working on Informix and Oracle database servers, and am unaware of any escape functions for databases which are to be connected through drivers such as OCI8 or odbc.

Could anybody explain a little about the security measures for these databases.

Comment: So, you have always did it wrong :) Only strings should be escaped. For the numbers it helps nothing

Comment: You would be surprised how sinister some SQL Injections can be!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do sanitization unless you are doing VERY dynamic queries. Parameterized queries are the *right* way to go.
[Here's the PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which describes how to do this.

Comment: I can't even think of a "very dynamic" situation where you would need to do it.  If you're allowing the user to enter any part of the SQL code then they should be a trusted user.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Oracle has bind variables that automatically take care of preventing sql injection. Neat, huh? :)
Adam Hawkes uses the PDO library. I personally use oci8 with the [oci_bind_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) function.

Comment: Actually, I don't know *any* PHP! I know of *other* people who use the PDO library though. It is not specific to OCI, so once you've used it with a familiar DB you can switch over to another DB without re-learning everything. I hear good things about oci_bind_by_name too, though.

Comment: I think, if your bind variable is containing a single '(' in it then the query will fail.